# SSRS subtract 1 day when using calender

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get the correct date from calendar using expression. But with my code, it gives 32 days and I need 31 days. How can I use DateAdd with this?

```
="Date: " + cstr(left(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value, 4) + "." + Mid(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value, 5, 2)+ "." + Right(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value,2))
```

Comment: Is `Parameters!KP2Ky.Value` a date? Can you post an example?

Comment: Yes it is. Right now, if i pick a month, like Jan, result looks like: 2019.01.32

Comment: Is it stored as a string or date?

Comment: If the parameter is set to Date then its not going to return an invalid date? You must have a different parameter type. Or your conversion is wrong, maybe you just want to use `Format(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value, "yyyy.MM.dd")'

Comment: It's stored as string

Comment: You pick a month from a parameter and you try to get the last day of the month?

Comment: yeah. Last day of the month

Comment: Its a parameter - what do you mean its stored as a string? Set it to DateTime and use it properly?

Comment: You're going to need to provide full information on your so called `calendar` parameter - because as it stands we have no idea how you are getting 32 - but if you have created it yourself its probably the code you are using to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but I couldn't figure out how you are getting 32 in your result.

I would make the parameter a DATE type.

For the last day of the month previous to the selected month, you could use

```
="Date: " & FORMAT(DATEADD("d", 0 - DAY(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value), Parameters!KP2Ky.Value), "yyyy.MM.dd")
```

The last day of the selected month is a little more complicated:

```
="Date: " & FORMAT(DATEADD("d", 0 - DAY(DATEADD("M", 1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value), Parameters!KP2Ky.Value))), DATEADD("M", 1, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(Parameters!KP2Ky.Value), Parameters!KP2Ky.Value))), "yyyy.MM.dd")
```